# Laravel 4 - Check if a user has used some content

Tags: laravel-4, eloquent, relationship, pivot-table

I'm making a web page where my users can create two types of content: 'Activities' and 'Collection of activities'. And I want to check if the current user has already used an Activity in any of his Collections.

The relationship between these two kinds of content is `belongsToMany`. Every Activity can be used in some Collection, and every Collection han have a lot of Activities... So there is a pivot table to handle it.

I got my `Activity ID` my `User ID`, but I don't know how to do it.

Any idea?? Thank you very much!!

**Edit**

My Controller:

```
$actividads = Actividad::orderBy('created_at', 'DESC')->paginate(10);
    $id_user = Sentry::getUser()->id;
    $fichas = Ficha::where('user_id', $id_user)->orderBy('created_at', 'DESC')->get();

    $user = User::find($id_user);
    $actividadEnFicha = Actividad::has('fichas')
                                ->get();
```

And my View:

```
@foreach($actividads as $actividad)

    @foreach($actividadEnFicha as $a)
        @if($actividad->id == $a->id)
            {{ $a->id }}
        @endif
    @endforeach
@endforeach
```

I would like to show the name of the `ficha` instead of the `$a->id` (id actividad)... But I don't still know how to get it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming relation `activities` (`User hasMany Activity`):

```
$user = User::find($userId);

// returns Activity only if it belongs to one or more collections, null otherwise
$activityInCollection = $user->activities()
  ->has('collections')
  // with('collections') to eager load collections
  ->find($activityId);

// returns Activity with given id only if it does not belong to any collection
$activitiyWithoutCollections = $user->activities()
  ->has('collections', '=', 0);

// all activities of the user, that belong to one or more collections
$activitiesInCollections = $user->activities()
  ->has('collections')
  // with('collections') to eager load collections
  ->get();

// all activities of the user, that belong to exactly 3 collections
$activitiesInCollections = $user->activities()
  ->has('collections', '=', 3)
  // with('collections') to eager load collections
  ->get();
```

and so on...

Comment: Thank you very much!! It works!! But I still have a problem with my view. I want to show in my view the name of every Collection (I call it 'ficha') I've already used. I edit the question with my code...

Comment: `fichas` will be `Eloquent\Collection`, so you need `$a->fichas->first()->name` or loop through those fichas. And I suggest eager loading them, like in the edit.

Comment: What if I want to get a list of all fichas name, and not only the `first()`??

Comment: `@foreach ($actividad->fichas as $ficha) <li>{{ $ficha->name }}</li>` for example

Comment: uopssss easy!! Thanksss ;)

Comment: it works good, but it is comparing the `collections` created by the current user with the `activities` created by himself. But I would like to compare his `collections` with all the activities (whoever has done it). Do you know how to do it?

Comment: Simply `Activity::has...` instead of `$user->activities()->has`

Comment: I already had tried it, but @deczo I think I'm doing something wrong... because with that, I'm comparing the current `activity` with all the activities that belong to EVERY `collection (I call it 'ficha')`, and I want to compare the activity with all the activities that belong only the current user's `collections (or fichas)`... I'm gonna edit my question with my code...

Comment: So just try the other way around: `$user->fichas()->whereHas('activities', function ($q) use ($activityId) {$q->where('activities.id', $activityId);})->first();`